# AJAX: post an array of values to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know almost nothing about javascript/jquery:

I have an ajax call that returns entries formatted in an html table like so:

```
Stuff |   Other stuff  |  delete stuff
------|----------------|-------------------------
value1| from database  | delete this entry button
------|----------------|-------------------------
value2| from database  | delete this entry button
```

the column above that says 'delete stuff' has a button that will call a method to delete that entry. What i've been trying to do is add a checkbook to the end of each row, and send an array to php to do a multiple record delete.

here is the call:

```
 $('#menu-notifications').click(function() { 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/admin/notifications/ajax_view_notifications/' + <?= $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#notifications-modal .modal-body table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
                            $('#notifications-modal .modal-body table tr:last').after(
                                                    '<tr><td>' + htmlDecode(obj.message) + '</td>' + 
                                                    '<td>' + obj.created_by + '</td>' + 
                                                    '<td>' + obj.created_dt + '</td>' + 
                                                    '<td><div class="btn-group">' + 
                                                    '<a href="/admin/notifications/ajax_delete_notification/' + obj.id + '" class="btn btn-mini delete-notification" id="delete-notification" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>' +
                                                    // here should be a checkbox to mark for deletion
                                                    '</div></td></tr>');
                        });
                    }
                });
```

I've added the checkbox successfully,  but every attempt to have a `<?=form_open();?>` or open another form has caused the page to not load at all (nothing in the console).

TO SUM IT UP:  Im trying to have a checkbox appended to the end of each row, i can mark this chexbox, and send each marked checkbox to a method.

Comment: What does the generated html look like, does your form wrap the table?

Comment: Currently, there isnt a form at all. Just a method call. I've been having issues getting a form set up in this particular format.  As far as generated html, im not sure what you mean. Its just a table being generated by jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create each checkbox with an [HTML array](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays), it's value will be the element id, then you would need an action (like a '*Delete All*' button) that sends the data to PHP with Ajax (no form needed):

```
$('#menu-notifications').click(function() {
    // Simpler: use getJSON
    $.getJSON('/admin/notifications/ajax_view_notifications/' + <?= $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>)
    // Clearner: use promises :)
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#notifications-modal .modal-body table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            // Create a row
            var row = $('<tr>');
            // Crete cells
            var cells =
                '<td>' + htmlDecode(obj.message) + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + obj.created_by + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + obj.created_dt + '</td>' +
                // We use this identified cell to create our delete functionality
                '<td class="delete-row"></td>';
            // Fill the row
            row.append(cells);
            // Create the delete button
            var deleteButton = $('<a>', {
                 'href':        '/admin/notifications/ajax_delete_notification/' + obj.id
                ,'class':       'btn btn-mini delete-notification'
                // We can't have duplicate ids, so no ids here
                // ,id:         'delete-notification'
                ,'data-dismiss':'modal'
                ,'html':        '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'
            });
            // Crete the checkbox
            var checkbox = $('input', {
                 'type':        'checkbox'
                // We use an HTML array
                ,'name':        'rowsToDelete[]'
                ,'value':       obj.id
            });
            // Append the button and the checkbox to the row
            // I ignore the .btn-group on purpose
            row.find('.delete-row')
                .append(deleteButton)
                .append(checkbox);
            // We add the row to the DOM
            $('#notifications-modal .modal-body table tr:last').append(row);
        });
    });

});

// To delete in group we use a different call, let's say, a 'Delete All' button
$('#delete-all').click(function() {
    // We serialize the info of all the buttons
    // Find all checkbox under the .delete-row class and serialize it
    data = $('.delete-row').find(':checkbox').serialize();
    // Send the data to PHP
    $.post('/admin/notifications/ajax_delete_notification/delete_a_bunch', data)
    // PHP would receive $_POST['rowsToDelete'] = [1, 2, 4, 20]
    .done(function(data) {
        alert('All selected rows were deleted');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('No rows deleted :/');
    });
});
```

---

### Test snippet

```js
// To delete in group we use a different call, let's say, a 'Delete All' button
$('#delete-all').click(function() {
    // We serialize the info of all the buttons
    // Find all checkbox under the .delete-row class and serialize it
    data = $('.delete-row').find(':checkbox').serialize();
  
    // Alert the data (test only)
    $("#r").text(data.replace(/deleteRow/g, '$_POST[deleteRow]').replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]').replace(/\&/g, ";\n") + ';');
  
    /*
    // Send the data to PHP
    $.post('/admin/notifications/ajax_delete_notification/delete_a_bunch', data)
    // PHP would receive $_POST['rowsToDelete'] = [1, 2, 4, 20]
    .done(function(data) {
        alert('All selected rows were deleted');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('No rows deleted :/');
    });
    */
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
}
#r {
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Dummy header</th>
   <th>Dummy header</th>
   <th>Dummy header</th>
   <th>Check to delete</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td class="delete-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteRow[]" value="2">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td class="delete-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteRow[]" value="3">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td class="delete-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteRow[]" value="6">
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td>Dummy Text</td>
   <td class="delete-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="deleteRow[]" checked value="10">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<hr>
<button id="delete-all">Delete all elements</button>
<pre id="r"></pre>
```

Comment: fantastic! Slight modifications got me exactly what I needed!